# How to display an array of objects in table in two columns?

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I want to display array of objects in 2 columns in a table.  what is the easiest method to display the list as two columns?

```
const columns = [
    {
      subHeading: "A",
      subText: ["1", "2"]
    },
    {
      subHeading: "B",
      subText: ["3", "4"]
    },
    {
      subHeading: "C",
      subText: ["5", "6"]
    },
    {
      subHeading: "D",
      subText: ["7", "8"]
    }
  ];
```

Desired display on HTML Page:

```
A B
C D
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. One of the way is using css `grid`

Comment: The question is not clear. It doe snot answer why A, B will be in one row . Does your requirement need only two columns and two rows?

Comment: @brk what is unclear about the question? The question is how to add them in 2 columns. There was never mentioned that the amount of rows matter nor that the elements is specifically 4 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Grid` here as:

[`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-fire-t4wvzy?file=/src/App.js:340-505)

```
<div style={{ display: "grid", gridTemplateColumns: "1fr 1fr" }}>
  {columns.map((col, i) => {
    return <h1>{col.subHeading}</h1>;
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: Do I need to write this code in JS? Sorry I am new with this

Comment: This is a `react` code snippet. Are you using vanillla JS? Then I can help you with that

Answer (score 0):

Displaying content in 2 columns can be easily done with CSS-Grid by using `display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);`. This is not an appropriate task for a table as it is not tabular data!

Creating the content dynamically can be done by looping through the arrays and using `createElement`:

```js
const COLUMNS = [{
    subHeading: "A",
    subText: ["1", "2"]
  },
  {
    subHeading: "B",
    subText: ["3", "4"]
  },
  {
    subHeading: "C",
    subText: ["5", "6"]
  },
  {
    subHeading: "D",
    subText: ["7", "8"]
  }
];

// EventListener to wait until the DOM is loaded
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', printArray);

// function to loop of the array and read every subHeading and subText
function printArray() {
  COLUMNS.forEach(object => {
    createSection(object.subHeading, object.subText);
  })
}


// function to create new sections
function createSection(heading, text) {
  // creates a new section
  let newSection = document.createElement('section');
  
  // adds the title to the section
  let newTitle = document.createElement('h2');
  newTitle.textContent = heading;
  newSection.appendChild(newTitle);
  
  // adds the text elements to the sections
  text.forEach(arrayElement => {
    let newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
    newParagraph.textContent = arrayElement;
    newSection.appendChild(newParagraph);
  });
  
  // appends the sections to the body
  document.body.appendChild(newSection);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
}
```

I just added the elements to the body directly. You can add them into a container of you choice.